Why is my code giving me the error Internal Server Error 500 even though it is working on postman when sending a post request
I have this code which adds a doctor specialization to the database in which the doctor has to upload an image and some text fields with a drop down
Future<void> addSpecializationToServer(
      {required BuildContext context}) async {
    String selectedItemsText = selectedItems.join(', ');
   // final token = LocalStorage.getString(key: 'token');
    final doctorId = LocalStorage.getString(key: 'id');

    final apiUrl = Uri.parse('${UtilGlobals.baseUrl}/add/specializations');
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', apiUrl);

    request.fields['doctor_id'] = doctorId.toString();
    request.fields['degree_name'] = degreeController.text;
    request.fields['institute_name'] = instituteController.text;
    request.fields['passing_year'] = yearOfPassingController.text;
    request.fields['certification_name'] = "certification";
    request.fields['specialization'] = selectedItemsText;
    request.fields['categories_id'] = selectedItemId.toString();
    var certificationImage = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'certication_image', certificateImage!.path);
    request.files.add(certificationImage);
    var response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      log('Specialization Added Successfully');
      getSpecialiationByDoctor();
      degreeController.clear();
      instituteController.clear();
      certificationController.clear();
      registrationNoController.clear();
      yearOfPassingController.clear();
      specializationCategory.clear();
      Get.back();
    } else {
      log('error in add Specialization ${response.reasonPhrase.toString()} + ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

and it's logging out [log] error in add Specialization Internal Server Error + 500 from my side but on postman is working fine


I tried to add an image using image picker and added a text field with a text field controller for it to add to the database but it's not working although they are being fetched. And the server is not down as i have tried from postman multiple times.

Can you switch your server to http (vs https) - and grab a packet capture of both requests? There's a possibility that your server doesn't like lower case header names.
